# How Preventing deletion of a message or prevent DELETE requests to my azure AD App (Microsoft Graph) apis?

Tags: azure, microsoft-graph-api

I'm creating an Application to access my Mail
so far everything works fine.

My app has only **Mail.ReadWrite** And I didn't find anything related to 
preventing deletion of a message or to prevent DELETE requests to my App.

This Page is only about how to delete a message, but there's nothing about how to prevent users from doing.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/message-delete?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http

So is there anyway I can prevent or limit the user from deleting Messages (Mails).

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for reaching out. To my knowledge there isn't currently a way to prevent delete requests once the `Mail.ReadWrite` permission has been granted to the app. Would you consider filing a [feature request on the M365 Developer Platform](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform) so we can look into this?

Let me know if this helps and if you have further questions.